# Safari caching PDF, but chrome doesn't

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, safari

I´m using object tag to show PDF files, but it´s not working correctly in safari.

In my Rails application, I generate a new file over the older one, with same name, but safari keeps showing old file until I reload the page.

My javascript function to show PDF:

```
function showPDF(fileName, title) {
    var h = ($(window).height() - 150);
    var page = '<object data=' + fileName + '#view=Fit" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="' + h + '"px">' +
        '<p>Cant´t visualize. <a href="'+fileName+'">Click here to download</a></p>'+
        '</object>';

    bootbox.dialog({
        title: title,
        message: page
    });
}
```

Any suggestions?

#### update

The follow snippets was generated by the bootbox:

file1:

```
<div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="bootbox-close-button close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Atestado</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="bootbox-body">
     <object data="/output6.pdf#view=Fit&quot;" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="694" px"="" internalinstanceid="3">
        <p>Cant´t visualize. <a href="/output6.pdf">Click here to download</a></p>
     </object>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

file2:

```
div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="bootbox-close-button close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Atestado</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="bootbox-body">
     <object data="/output6.pdf#view=Fit&quot;" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="383" px"="" internalinstanceid="8">
        <p>Cant´t visualize. <a href="/output6.pdf">Click here to download</a></p>
     </object>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this file is in the server, like: public/file.pdf

Comment: To try to understand the problem better, please, post the generate HTML for the bootbox on the first two files to be loaded